# How to retrieve azure iot-hub storage account name

Tags: json, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

I am writing a PowerShell script that creates iot-hub account with storage account and a streamAnalytics job.

For updating the json file for the streamAnalytics job, I need to retrieve the storage account name that has just been created. Unfortunately, AzureRM has no function to retrieve storage account **Name**.
Any suggestions on how to do that?

My current script receives it as input from user, but I want the script to be automated and with no need for user input.

Answer (score 2):

got it, I just used:

```
$storageAccountName = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $IotHubResourceGroupName).storageAccountName
```